# Is it possible to display previous post revision?

Tags: loop, revisions

I want to be able to loop through my posts, but **for every post to this:**

**1)** check if some custom field is true or false.

**2)** if is true just display the post's data (*the_title, the_content...*).

**3)** if is false display the same structure of data (*the_title, the_content...*) but with the pervious revision of this post.

Is it possible? and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First we look into the `wp_get_post_autosave` function

It's informative to see how the core function `wp_get_post_autosave()` uses 
the `wp_get_post_revisions()` function.

It loops over all revisions from

```
$revisions = wp_get_post_revisions( 
    $post_id, 
    array( 
        'check_enabled' => false 
    ) 
);
```

and then uses:

```
foreach ( $revisions as $revision ) {
    if ( false !== strpos( $revision->post_name, "{$post_id}-autosave" ) ) {
        if ( $user_id && $user_id != $revision->post_author )
            continue;

        return $revision;
    }
}
```

to return the first revision with a slug containing `"{$post_id}-autosave"` and  where the `$user_id` possibly matches it's author.

**Alternative**

Now `wp_get_post_revisions()` is a wrapper for `get_children()`, so I wonder why it has to fetch all the revisions for the given post, before filtering out a single one. Why not try to fetch it directly, only what's needed? When we try e.g. the following (PHP 5.4+):

```
$revisions = wp_get_post_revisions(
    $post_id,
    [
        'offset'       => 1,    // Start from the previous change (ofset changed to offset)
        'posts_per_page'  => 1,    // Only a single revision
        'name'            => "{$post_id}-autosave-v1",
        'check_enabled'   => false,
    ]
);
```

then the `posts_per_page` will not have any effect. After playing around with this I managed to get the following to work with the `posts_per_page` argument:

```
$revisions = wp_get_post_revisions(
    $post_id,
    [
        'offset'           => 1,    // Start from the previous change
        'posts_per_page'  => 1,    // Only a single revision
        'post_name__in'   => [ "{$post_id}-autosave-v1" ],
        'check_enabled'   => false,
    ]
);
```

### Get only the previous revision

Now we can adjust the above to only fetch the previous revision, i.e. that's not an *auto-save*:

```
$revisions = wp_get_post_revisions(
    $post_id,
    [
        'offset'           => 1,    // Start from the previous change
        'posts_per_page'  => 1,    // Only a single revision
        'post_name__in'   => [ "{$post_id}-revision-v1" ],
        'check_enabled'   => false,
    ]
);
```

Here we target the `{$post_id}-revision-v1` slug.

Note the here we use the `v1`, but we could adjust that if needed later on.

### Example

So to finally answer your question, here's a suggestion:

```
$show = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'somekey', true );

if( $show )
{
    // Template part
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content' );
}
else
{
    // Fetch the previous revision only
    $revisions = wp_get_post_revisions(
        get_the_ID(),
        [
            'offset'           => 1,    // Start from the previous change
            'posts_per_page'  => 1,    // Only a single revision
            'post_name__in'   => [ sprintf( "%d-revision-v1", get_the_ID() ) ],
            'check_enabled'   => false,
        ]
    );

    if( $revisions )
    {
        $post = reset( $revisions );
        setup_postdata( $post );

        // Template part
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content' );

        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    else
    {
         // Some fallback here
    }
}
```

Hopefully you can adjust it further to your needs!

Comment: Thanks! wow, you really worked it out all the way :) you saved me so much time!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear it worked for you @Ben

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. You can access to post's revisions using `wp_get_post_revisions($post_id)` function. It returns array of post's revision, first element of an array is the same as current version of post so you should take second's element values.